# Convert complex to integer matrix in python

Tags: python, type-conversion, complex-numbers

Is there a way to convert a complex matrix to an integer matrix in python?
[Solution in Wolfram Mathematica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uia3.png) . 
 E. g.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.zeros((6,6),dtype=complex)
A[1,1]= 1.+1j
A[3,2]= 2.1-1j
print(A)
```

returns

```
[[0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j]
 [0. +0.j 1. +1.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j]
 [0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j]
 [0. +0.j 0. +0.j 2.1-1.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j]
 [0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j]
 [0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j 0. +0.j]]
```

But i would like to have something like

```
[[0 0   ...
 [0 1+j ...
```

I have tried

```
A.astype(np.int64)
```

but returns

```
... ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. For a good question you should post the code that you have tried. You could at least provide the matrices you have created and what library you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[12.0, 12.51 + 1.44J], [2.34 + 1.2J, 7.98 - 3.4J] ])

y = np.int_(x.real) + (np.int_(x.imag))*1J
```

Then you can in principle substitute `np.int_` with other functions (`floor`, `round` etc etc).

Comment: Have you tried your code before posting? Multiplying by `1j` casts the result to a Complex, that in Python is, loosely speaking, the union of two Floats. When you sum an Integer and a Complex, the integer is cast to a complex with null imaginary part and the result is still a Complex, i.e., two Floats.  I could have spared to me, to you and to the rest of the audience all of this tirade if you tried your code before posting.

Comment: Thank you GuaCaLa, it works for real numbers but not for complex.